# Global variable & local scope in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I'm a newbie and wrote a simple code to learn the basic concept of global and local scope in Meteor. The code is a follows:

```
    var sec=0;
    var min=0;

    console.log("Hello World")

    if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Template.Output.helpers({
        'secs':function(){  
            return sec;
        },
        'mins':function(){  
            return min;
        }
    });

    Template.Input.events({
        'submit form': function(event){

          event.preventDefault();
          min = event.target.minutes.value;
          sec = min * 60;
          console.log(min);
          console.log(sec);   
        }
    });

    }

if (Meteor.isServer) {

}
```

When I run meteor it will display 0 minutes and 0 seconds, but when I entered some value and press the submit button the value does not change even though I have declared that min and sec as global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sec` and `min` variables are plain JS vars, you need a reactive data source such as `Session` for the Meteor magic to happen.

```
Session.set("sec",0);
Session.set("min",0);

Template.Output.helpers({
    'secs':function(){  
        return Session.get("sec");
    },
    'mins':function(){  
        return Session.get("min");
    }
});

Template.Input.events({
    'submit form': function(event){

      event.preventDefault();
      var min=event.target.minutes.value;
      var sec=min*60;
      Session.set("min",min);
      Session.set("sec",sec);
      console.log(min);
      console.log(sec);   
    }
});
```